Как исправить ошибку: "create_tile: Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the..."?
Когда я создаю TileMapLayer в Godot и добавляю туда тайлы, вылезают ошибки, много ошибок:
Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the space the tile would cover.
The TileSetAtlasSource atlas has no tile at (31, 1).
TileSetAtlasSource has no tile at (31, 1).
Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the space the tile would cover.
The TileSetAtlasSource atlas has no tile at (32, 1).
TileSetAtlasSource has no tile at (32, 1).
Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the space the tile would cover.
The TileSetAtlasSource atlas has no tile at (33, 1).
TileSetAtlasSource has no tile at (33, 1).
Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the space the tile would cover.
The TileSetAtlasSource atlas has no tile at (37, 1).
TileSetAtlasSource has no tile at (37, 1).
Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the space the tile would cover.
The TileSetAtlasSource atlas has no tile at (38, 1).
TileSetAtlasSource has no tile at (38, 1).
Cannot create tile. The tile is outside the texture or tiles are already present in the space the tile would cover.
The TileSetAtlasSource atlas has no tile at (39, 1).
TileSetAtlasSource has no tile at (39, 1).
...

Как это исправить?

Исправить это очень просто.

Выберите снизу "Набор тайлов"

Нажмите на три точки:


Нажмите "Удалить тайлы вне текстуры"


Готово!
